# What does Wordpress mean by they have full rights to content

Tags: posts, wp-admin, content

I am pondering publishing my blog. I'm leaning more towards WordPress however, I don't want to worry about WordPress doing whatever they want whenever they want withmy blog because I have signed up for the basic plan (I'm new to blogging so I'm assuming I should start with the basics) depending on how well my blog does I intend to upgrade to one of the more advanced accounts.

In the meantime I read in this forum that Wordpress has full rights to content..how so? Full rights meaning no legal action can be taken against them for the reproduction or even stealing of blog posts, pictures, etc? Can they just use content as they wish? How does this work?

If I have posted this in the wrong section or if this question has been asked before please don't get upset like I stated I am new to blogging and I'm trying to gain insight on the best route I should take.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty off-topic -- this site is meant for WordPress programming questions -- but here's an answer anyways.

If you're referring to [WordPress.com's Terms of Service](http://en.wordpress.com/tos/), what you are granting WordPress (actually Automattic, WordPress's parent corporation) is as follows:

> By submitting Content to Automattic for inclusion on your Website, you grant Automattic a world-wide, royalty-free, and non-exclusive license to reproduce, modify, adapt and publish the Content solely for the purpose of displaying, distributing and promoting your blog. If you delete Content, Automattic will use reasonable efforts to remove it from the Website, but you acknowledge that caching or references to the Content may not be made immediately unavailable.

What this means is that, while you retain the copyright to your work, Automattic is allowed to publish it on WordPress.com (which is what you're signing up for) without paying you or anything like that.

See also: http://tosdr.org/#wordpress-com

**Caveat:** I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for your prompt reply! I will try to figure out how to navigate this site is I will know where to post Thank you again!!